# Generating token in django

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to django. I'm working on resetting the password with PasswordResetView. I've made all the necessary configurations. All the views are working properly(reset,done,confirm,complete) but the email is not being sent. I'm using file based method. The mail content is also stored in a text file successfully.
The text file

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Subject: Password reset on 127.0.0.1:8000
From: webmaster@localhost
To: user1991@gmail.com
Date: Fri, 08 May 2020 13:07:44 -0000
Message-ID: 
 <158894326451.7060.3441580324173819052@DESKTOP-G46QTJT.localdomain>


You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at 127.0.0.1:8000.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/reset-password/confirm/Ng/5gb-4468fc4f5f5c9ad67d90/

Your username, in case you’ve forgotten: test@5

Thanks for using our site!

The 127.0.0.1:8000 team



-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But i didn't received the mail. Hoping for a solution. Atleast I want to know how to generate the one time url alone like the one django created automatically.

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for tutorial project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '!ku^2ct1u^jmk3+_8emila*@r2(9)avhsgf1@rnfhxb=30^4bp'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'tutorial.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tutorial.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tutorial.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile'

LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = [
    r'accounts/register',
]

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "sent_emails")
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'projectkesamad@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Kesavan@pro'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy, reverse
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    LoginView,LogoutView,PasswordResetView,PasswordResetDoneView,PasswordResetConfirmView,PasswordResetCompleteView
    )
app_name='accounts'

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.home,name='accounts_home_page'),
    path('login/',LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'),name='login_page'),
    path('logout/',LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'),name='logout_page'),
    path('register/',views.registration,name='register_page'),
    path('profile/',views.profile,name='profile'),
    path('profile/edit_profile/',views.edit_profile,name='edit-profile'),
    path('profile/change-password/',views.change_password,name='edit-profile'),

    path('profile/reset-password/',PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/reset_password.html',success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')),name='password_reset'),
    path('profile/reset-password/done/',PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('profile/reset-password/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')),name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('profile/reset-password/complete/',PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),name='password_reset_complete'),

]
```

Comment: Can you show your config fie (probably settings.py). Also, If you are using allauth/oauth, do mention.

Comment: @MuhammadHashirHassan I have updated the settings and url file

Comment: Did you try Email_Backend from ```file based``` to ```EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'```.

It should show email on the console is it working?

Comment: Yes it's working

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working as it is expected. The filebased Email_Backend is used to store emails in local directory **instead** of actually sending this to your email.
If you are trying to receive email in your gmail account, change your backend settings to `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`

> Make sure that SMTP congifuration of your gmail account is alright and it allows access to django: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

your settings.py should look like this:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "xyz@gmail.com" # enter valid email address of which the smtp settings your configured
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "yourpassword"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

The above solutions should work but you can also send email by ***send_mail***

```
subject = 'Thank you for registering to our site'
          message = 'this is a test message'
          email_from = 'xyz@gmail.com'
          recipient_list = ['reciever@gmail.com', ]
          connection = [
              'xyz@gmail.com',
              'mypassword',
              False,
          ]
         send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list, connection)
```

for this you will have to import send_mail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/

Comment: Thank you so much it's working fine now. I'm getting this error now Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/reset-password/confirm/Ng/set-password/index.html

Comment: It  is looking for index.html but not found. Make sure it is in the right folder you can first test the default templates of allauth. Also check if you have included urls("allauth").


This is entirely a different error so please accept this answer and ask this in another question with your file directory image and stack trace (console) so in future other people facing the issue can benefit from the answer.